# How to save an input value in ASP.NET with razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code on my View :

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Periode de Validation")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    Mois:
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PART1_MOIS must be a number."
    id="PART1_MOIS" name="PART1_MOIS" style="width: 80px" type="text" value="" />
    Ans :
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PART1_ANS must be a number."
    id="PART1_ANS" name="PART1_ANS" style="width: 80px" type="text" value="" />
    Total en mois :
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PART1_fPeriodeValid must be a number."
        id="PART1_fPeriodeValid" name="PART1_fPeriodeValid" style="width: 80px" type="text" value="" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fPeriodeValid)
</div>
```

I want to convert period in `year + month` in month, so i have this script :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>jQuery(function ($) {
            $(":text[id*=_MOIS],:text[id*=_ANS]").blur(function () {
                var MOIS = $(":text[id*=_MOIS]").val();
                var ANS = $(":text[id*=_ANS]").val();
                var total = MOIS / 1 + ANS * 12;
                $(":text[id*=fPeriodeValid]").val(total);
            });
        });</script>
```

but I don't know how to save this result (input button periodeValid) on my database ...

I have tried this :

**Total en mois :**

`<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PART1_fPeriodeValid must be a number." id="PART1_fPeriodeValid" name="PART1_fPeriodeValid" style="width: 80px" type="text" value="@Model.fPeriodeValide" />`

My model is like this : `public int? fPeriodeValid { get; set; }`

Comment: how does your controller look like? it it passing the value to the controller?

Comment: also instead of using <input> try using @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fPeriodeValid, new { @data-val="true", @data-val-number="" })

so its mapped with your model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mvc modelbinder Use from input name to create your action model.
if you have a model like:

```
public class myModel
{
public int? fPeriodeValid { get; set; }
}
```

You Must change **PART1_fPeriodeValid** to  **fPeriodeValid**

```
<input  id="PART1_fPeriodeValid" name="fPeriodeValid" ... />
Or
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.fPeriodeValid)
```

And your Action Like this

```
 public ActionResult Create(myModel model){
}
```

Comment: It works with the first solution !!! So really thank you ! I have tried also with `name="@Model.fPeriodValid"` but I didn't think like this...